# Как разбить страницу в HTML?

Tags: html, css

Страница – нужно её порезать в HTML, чтобы шапка тянулась, а кнопка по центру всегда была по центру, на формы и кнопки прописать action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На простом примере:

```
<div style="width: 100%; text-align:center; background: grey;">Шапка</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button style="text-align: center;">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Действия навешиваются на форму с помощью атрибута `action`.